# What do I have to do to get hook_form_alter picked up?

Tags: hooks, 8

Trying to move from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8.  First step is to get a custom module with `hook_form_alter()` and the Devel module working so that I can see how bad I am messing things up.

To do so, I made a custom module with the following files.

**mymodule.info.yml**

```
name: My Module
type: module
description: "Custom module"
package: Custom
core: 8.x
```

**mymodule.module**

```
<?php

function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  dpm($form);
  print_r($form);
}
```

**Other steps**

- I enabled both the Devel module and this custom module.
- I gave anonymous users permission to view devel information.
- I made sure the Status block was enabled on the Block Admin page.
- I cleared all caches via the Pantheon admin interface.
- I tried using `print_r($form)`, `dpm($form)`, and `var_dump($form)`.

However, when I refresh `/user/login`, I don't see any output from `dpm()`, so the hook isn't getting picked up for some reason.  What else do I need to do?

Comment: That's all you need to do (literally just done the same thing myself and the `dpm` is there). I have had some pretty bad problems with other similar things today though, since going to 8.0.2, so it might be bugs. Just check to make sure you've got the Status Messages block being printed to the page to start with, that got me for a little while

Comment: If the module is installed then the issue is most likely the fact that you are outputting all forms that go through the hook which will overflow the session storage in db. I would suggest outputting only form id or only selected form based on the form id. On the other hand var_dump or print_r should work(if you're not seeing WSOD). Als you have mentioned dummy pages..are there any forms on any of those?

Comment: @Clive I do have the Status Messages block, but still no dice.  @Ivan Jaros I also tried `/user/login`, but I just see the normal login form, no output from `dpm()` or `var_dump()`, which I separately tried.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was something related to MultiDev, a Pantheon-specific feature.  By cloning back and forth between the main dev branch and my multidev branch, I was able to get the custom `hook_form_alter()` to work.